# How to create array of dims?

Tags: expl3

Array of ints is supported by expl3. But what about array of dims?

I need an integer-indexed array-variable, that would hold dim values. The array size should be able to grow on the go instead of being known in advance (I wouldn't know how many dim values it is going to hold, the size depends on the nesting level of custom environments). For example, if a counter is 1, then array size is 1; if the counter grows to 3, then array should grow to 3 indices.

I need something like an indexed variable `myDim` below.

```
myDim[1]=5.0pt
myDim[2]=7.35pt
...
```

EDIT:

```
% \myDim = 0 here
\begin{myEnv} % myDim[1] = 5.0pt; current index = 1
  \begin{myEnv} % myDim[2] = 7.35pt; current index = 2
  \end{myEnv} % current index = 1
\end{myEnv} % current index = 0
```

Comment: Why not use a seq? That allows retreiving items and usage as a stack. Is there something missing?

Comment: there isn't really any difference between integers and dims, in fact intarray is a wrapper around using `\fontdimen` to store values. So you could just use intarray

Comment: What's the scale here? If you only want a small array, I'd use a classical hash-table based approach.

Comment: @bp2017 because `5.5pt` isn't an integer literal, but it is the same as if you go `\count0=5.5pt` the count register gets set to 5 and the `.5pt` is typeset or generates an error depending where this occurs, but `\dimen0=5.5pt \count0=\dimen0` works as the dimen register is a legal count (taking the length in `sp`) even though 5.5pt is not.

Comment: not sure what that paste is intended to show or why you expected it to do something other than it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `intarray` can't change in size and assignments to it are always global, so you can't exploit the grouping of environments to emulate a behaviour like that (not easily, at least). The documentation of `l3intarray` does say:

> The use of `intarray` data is therefore recommended for cases where the need for fast access is of paramount importance.

which most of the times is not the case. If you aren't going to use an array with thousands of elements and access these elements thousands of times, then a `seq` variable is probably good enough for your case.

Here's an *ad hoc* implementation of an `array` data type which offers mostly the same interface as `l3intarray` but uses `expl3`'s `seq` data type underneath.

Interfaces:

- `\array_new:N ⟨array var⟩` — Creates a new `⟨array var⟩` variable with no elements.
- `\array_zero:N ⟨array var⟩` — Sets all elements of the `⟨array var⟩` to zero.
- `\array_allocate:Nn ⟨array var⟩ {⟨num items⟩}` — Allocates the `⟨array var⟩` to have `⟨num items⟩`, all equal to `0pt`. Items already in the `⟨array var⟩` are left untouched, so this can be used more than once.
- `\array_deallocate:N ⟨array var⟩` — Sets the `⟨array var⟩` to have no elements.
- `\array_count:N ⟨array var⟩` ★ — Expands to the number of elements in `⟨array var⟩`.
- `\array_item:Nn ⟨array var⟩ {⟨index⟩}` ★ — Expands to the dimension stored in the `⟨index⟩` position of `⟨array var⟩`. If `⟨index⟩` is larger than the size of `⟨array var⟩`, the function expands to nothing. If `⟨index⟩` is less than zero, the indices are counted from the end of the array.
- `\array_set:Nnn ⟨array var⟩ {⟨index⟩} {⟨dimen⟩}` — Sets the position `⟨index⟩` of the `⟨array var⟩` to contain `⟨dimen⟩`. If the `⟨array var⟩` doesn't have `⟨index⟩`, elements are allocated (with `\array_allocate:Nn`) until `⟨index⟩` exists.
- `\array_put_left:Nn ⟨array var⟩ {⟨dimexpr⟩}` — Adds an item at the end of `⟨array var⟩` and put `⟨dimexpr⟩` in it.
- `\array_put_right:Nn ⟨array var⟩ {⟨dimexpr⟩}` — Adds an item at the beginning of `⟨array var⟩` and put `⟨dimexpr⟩` in it.
- `\array_set_from_clist:Nn ⟨array var⟩ {⟨clist⟩}` — Sets the `⟨array var⟩` to contain the items of `⟨clist⟩`.
- `\array_log:N ⟨array var⟩` — Writes `⟨array var⟩` to the log file.
- `\array_show:N ⟨array var⟩` — Shows `⟨array var⟩` in the command window.

Functions marked with ★ are fully expandable. All assignments are local (If you need global assignments ask in the comments, please) except for `\array_new:N` which creates the `⟨array var⟩` globally.

Here's the code:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bparray.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{bparray}{2019-06-29}{0.1}{Array data type for expl3 (PHO)}
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_new:N \seq_new:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_count:N \seq_count:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_item:Nn \seq_item:Nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_deallocate:N \seq_clear:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_show:N \seq_show:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_log:N \seq_log:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_put_right:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \array_put_left:Nn \seq_put_left:Nn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \array_allocate:Nn #1#2
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnn { \array_count:N #1 + 1 } { #2 }
      { \exp_args:NNx \array_put_right:Nn #1 { \dim_use:N \c_zero_dim } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \array_set:Nnn #1#2
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT {#2} > { \array_count:N #1 }
      { \array_allocate:Nn #1 {#2} }
    \__array_set_item:Nnn #1 {#2}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__array_set_item:Nnn #1
  { \exp_after:wN \__array_item:wNn #1 \q_stop #1 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__array_item:wNn \s__seq #1 \q_stop #2#3#4
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \__array_item:nnwn
      { \exp_args:Nf \__seq_item:nN { \int_eval:n {#3} } #2 } { }
    #1
    \prg_collect_point:
    \__array_replace_item:Nn #2 {#4}
    \prg_break: \__seq_item:n { }
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__array_item:nnwn #1#2#3 \__seq_item:n #4
  {
    #3
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = 1
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__array_internal_tl {#2}
        \prg_break_collect:Nw \__array_set_item_end:n
      }
      {
        \exp_args:Nf \__array_item:nnwn
          { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } }
          { #2 \__seq_item:n {#4} }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__array_set_item_end:n #1
  { \exp_args:NV \__array_set_item_end:nnwn \l__array_internal_tl {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__array_set_item_end:nnwn #1 #2 \__array_replace_item:Nn #3 #4
  {
    \tl_set:Nx #3
      {
        \s__seq
        \exp_not:n {#1}
        \exp_not:N \__seq_item:n { \dim_eval:n {#4} }
        \exp_not:n {#2}
      }
    \prg_break:
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \__array_replace_item:Nn \use_none:nn
\cs_new:Npn \prg_break_collect:Nw #1 #2 \prg_collect_point: { #1{#2} }
\cs_new_eq:NN \prg_collect_point: \prg_do_nothing:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \array_zero:N #1
  { \exp_args:Nf \__array_zero:nN { \array_count:N #1 } #1 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__array_zero:nN #1#2
  {
    \array_deallocate:N #2
    \array_allocate:Nn #2 {#1}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \array_set_from_clist:Nn #1#2
  {
    \array_deallocate:N #1
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      { \exp_args:NNx \array_put_right:Nn #1 { \dim_eval:n {##1} } }
  }
\end{filecontents}
```

and a test document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bparray}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\array_new:N \l_bp_array
\array_log:N \l_bp_array \array_allocate:Nn \l_bp_array { 3 }
\array_log:N \l_bp_array \array_set:Nnn \l_bp_array { 5 } { 1 pt + 2.141592 pt }
\array_log:N \l_bp_array \array_zero:N \l_bp_array
\array_log:N \l_bp_array \array_set_from_clist:Nn \l_bp_array { 1pt, 2pt, 3pt }
\array_log:N \l_bp_array
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The `.log` then contains:

```latex
The sequence \l_bp_array is empty
> .
The sequence \l_bp_array contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}.
The sequence \l_bp_array contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}
>  {3.14159pt}.
The sequence \l_bp_array contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}
>  {0.0pt}.
The sequence \l_bp_array contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1.0pt}
>  {2.0pt}
>  {3.0pt}.
```

You can then easily define that environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bparray}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_myenv_int
\array_new:N \l_myenv_array
\array_set_from_clist:Nn \l_myenv_array { 5pt, 7.35pt }
\NewDocumentEnvironment {myEnv} { }
  { \int_incr:N \l_myenv_int } { }
\NewDocumentCommand \arrayitem { }
  { \array_item:Nn \l_myenv_array { \l_myenv_int } }
\NewDocumentCommand \arrayindex { }
  { \int_use:N \l_myenv_int }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
\begin{myEnv}
  Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
  \begin{myEnv}
    Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
  \end{myEnv}
  Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
\end{myEnv}
Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
\end{document}
```

the output is:

> [image]

---

However it doesn't look like you actually need dynamic allocation. The result above can be easily achieved with an `fparray` (with the difference that an index-out-of-bounds error can occur):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_myenv_int
\fparray_new:Nn \l_myenv_fparray { 2 }
\fparray_gset:Nnn \l_myenv_fparray { 1 } { 5pt }
\fparray_gset:Nnn \l_myenv_fparray { 2 } { 7.35pt }
\NewDocumentEnvironment {myEnv} { }
  { \int_incr:N \l_myenv_int } { }
\NewDocumentCommand \arrayitem { }
  { \dim_eval:n { \fparray_item:Nn \l_myenv_fparray { \l_myenv_int } pt } }
\NewDocumentCommand \arrayindex { }
  { \int_use:N \l_myenv_int }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
% Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par % Error
\begin{myEnv}
  Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
  \begin{myEnv}
    Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
  \end{myEnv}
  Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par
\end{myEnv}
% Array index = \arrayindex{} and array item = \arrayitem\par % Error
\end{document}
```

output:

> [image]